# Оптимизация выборки с интервалом

Tags: sql, mysql

Существует 3 таблицы: `users` - все пользователи сайта; `online_users` - онлайн пользователи; `news` - новости.

Задача - делать выборку актуальных новостей для каждого пользователя. Идея такова: через крон раз в 10 минут перебирать онлайн пользователей и ставить флаг в таблицу `users` на то, что для пользователя есть актуальные новости. Запрос составлять следующим образом.

1. `` SELECT `created_date` FROM `news` ORDER BY `created_date` DESC limit 1 `` - выбираем самую новую новость
2. `` SELECT `online_users`.`user_id` FROM `users` JOIN `online` ON `users`.`id` = `online`.`user_id` WHERE users.`last_readed_news` < '{$actual_news['created_date']}' AND `users`.`new_actual_news` = '0' `` - перебираем таблицу онлайн пользователей, и выбираем только тех, кто эту новость не читал ещё
3. `` UPDATE `users` SET `new_actual_news` = '1' WHERE `id` IN ({$Users_id}) `` -  ставим флаг того, что для пользоваетелей есть новости

---

Либо конкретно из под каждого пользователя делать запрос на проверку актуальных новостей, например раз в 10 минут.

---

Каким способом лучше организовать?

Comment: Новости для каждого пользователя уникальны? Т.е. Маша должна увидеть одни новости, а Петя в то же время совершенно другие?

Comment: Нет, новости для всех одни

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если новости для всех одни, то мне непонятно, зачем делать выборку для каждого пользователя. Сделайте выборку нужного количества новостей, как только первый посетитель откроет страницу с новостями. Если боитесь нагрузки - закешируйте результаты выборки, а при добавлении новой новости просто чистите кеш.

В таблице пользователей можно хранить id_last_news - ID последней прочитанной новости. Выводить все новости из news, у которых id больше указанного.

Comment: Ссылка на новость будет на каждой странице отображаться, не хотелось бы каждый раз лишний раз дёргать мускул

Comment: Можете хранить кешированные результаты в файлах и каждый раз дергать файловую систему. Но работа с БД обычно осуществляется на отдельном сервере и осуществляется быстрее, чем с файлами.
Вопрос только в том, где вам разрешена большая нагрузка - БД или файлы.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!